# How to auto replicate data in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, nosql

I am very new to cassandra and currently in early stage of project where i am studying cassandra.

Now since cassandra says to de-normalize data and replicate it. So, i have a following scenario :

I have table, `user_master`, for users. A user has

- subject [type text]
- hobbies [type list]
- uid [type int]
- around 40 more attributes

Now, a user wants to search for another user. This search should look for all user who matches the `subject` and `hobbies` provided by user. For this reason i am planning to make a different table `user_discovery` which will have following attribute only for every user

- subject [type text]
- hobbies [type list]
- uid [type int]

*other irrelevant attributes won't be part of this table.
Now my question is:

1. **Do i need to write on both tables for every insert/update in `user_master`? Can updation of `user_discovery` be automated when their is any insert/update in `user_master`.**
2. **Even after studying a bit, i am still not so much sure that making a separate table would increase the performance.Since, number of users would be same in both table (yes, number of column would be very less in `user_discovery`). Any comment on this would be highly appreciated.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of separate tables for queries is to have the key of the table contain what you are looking for.

You don't say what the key of your second table looks like, but your wording "the following attributes for every user" looks like you plan to have the user (Id?) as key. This would indeed have no performance advantage.

If you want to find users by their hobby make a table having the hobby as key, and the user id (or whatever it is you use to look up users) as columns. Write one row per hobby, listing all users having that hobby. Write the user into every row matching one of his hobbies.

Do the same for the subject (i.e. separate table, subject as key, user ids as columns).

Then, if you want to find a user having a list of specific hobbies, make one query per hobby, creating the intersection of the users.

To use these kind of lookup-tables you would have indeed to update all table every time you update a user.

Disclaimer: I used this kind of approach rather successfully in a relative complex setting managing a few hundred thousand users. However, this was two years ago, on a Cassandra 1.5 system. I haven't really looked into the new features of Cassandra 2.0, so I have no idea whether it would be possible to use a more elegant approach today.

Comment: Thanks Thomas , that was some really good explaination. I would appreciate if you can share some good reading for same.